# multi connection socket without threads doesnt recognize send

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

i have this error in my code and im not sure how to get rid of it. the code makes multi socket connections to the same server but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.py", line 73, in <module>
    connect_to(target, port)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.py", line 68, in connect_to
    int_nob.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(random.choice(user_agents)).encode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send
```

the part of the code that is affected

```
def connect_to(ip, port1):
    int_nob = int(200)#num of bots
    for x in range(0, int_nob):
        print(int(int_nob))

        int_nob -= 1
        int_nob = s.connect((ip, port1))
        int_nob.send("User-Agent: {}\r\n".format(random.choice(user_agents)).encode("utf-8"))
        if int_nob == 0:
            print(list_of_sockets)
            print("resending sockets of " + int_nob)
while True:
    connect_to(target, port)
```

i have got all the
 `import os
import random
s = socket.socket(AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREM)
port = 445` Etc.

i'm also not using threads